# If I add onClick to div the whole website doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm currently working on a seat booking website. I want to add an event listener to  such that when it is clicked it can call the function that will store the value of div. However, whenever I add the onClick event inside  the whole content in the website does not show up(only a blank page shows up). Is there something wrong with my code? Also, I'm quite new to react, so if possible can y'all explain your answers...?

Here is my code

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";

const Ticketing = () => {
    const [seat1, selectSeat1] = useState();
    const [seat2, selectSeat2] = useState();
    const [performance, selectPerformance] = useState("");
    const [seat, selectSeat] = useState("");
    return(
        <form>
            <div onClick={selectPerformance("Performance1")}>
                Performance 1
            </div>
            <div>
                Performance 2
            </div>

            <row>
                <div>
                    1
                </div>
                <div>
                    2
                </div>
                <div>
                    3
                </div>
                <div>
                    4
                </div>
                <div>
                    5
                </div>
                <div>
                    6
                </div>
            </row>
            
        </form>
    )

};
export default Ticketing;
```

---

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { HashRouter as Router,Route,Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Auth from "routes/Auth";
import Home from "routes/Home";
import Navigation from "components/Navigation";
import Mypage from "routes/Mypage";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import Ticketing from "routes/Ticketing";


const WebRouter = ({isLoggedIn}) => {
    return (
    < Router>
    {isLoggedIn && <Navigation/> }
        <Switch>
            {isLoggedIn? (
            <>
            <Route exact path="/Home">
                <Home/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/Mypage">
                <Mypage/>   
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/Ticketing">
                <Ticketing/>   
            </Route>
            </>
            ) : (
                <>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Auth/>
                </Route>
                <Redirect from = "*" to="/"/>
            </>

            )}
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    );
};

export default WebRouter;
```

Comment: What errors, if any, do you see in the console?

Comment: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: The above error occurred in the <Ticketing> component:

Comment: Going on a limb here, but I think it should be `onClick={() => selectPerformance("Performance1")`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in on Click function. Replace it with this piece of code.

```
 <div onClick={() => selectPerformance("Performance1")}>
     Performance 1
 </div>
```

Comment: It worked! thank you so much!!! If possible could you please explain why did this work?

Comment: this worked because, you have to pass a function as the event handler and you are directly setting the state in onClick which caused the problem, So as in the solution I passed  anonymous function in onClick.

Answer (score 1):

onClick event binding is wrong, you should pass a function to onClick, but you bind whatever is returned from `selectPerformance` function. Binding should be:

```
<div onClick={() => selectPerformance("Performance1")}>
 Performance 1
 </div>
```

Reason of too many re-renders:
In this react docs link (https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) under `Let’s quickly recap what’s going on and the order in which the methods are called:` part, 4th item tells:

`Thanks to the setState() call, React knows the state has changed, and calls the render() method again to learn what should be on the screen.`

So the reason is: when you update `performance` with `selectPerformance` function, state-related part gets re-rendered because there was a change in state. When state is re-rendered, `selectPerformance` gets called again. Because of that, state-related part gets re-rendered again, so `selectedPerformance` gets called again. Because of that state-related part ... infinite loop.